# MongoDB Filter for both matched and un-matched conditions

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a scenario where I *think* I might need to use $cond to set an attribute in $project (aggregation) based on whether an existing attribute exists in an array of strings.

Take the following data as a simplified example...

```
var teamMemberFilter = ['Dave', 'Kate'];

[
    {
        ticketId: '1',
        ticketDesc: 'Dummy ticket 1',
        assignments: [
            {
                asignee: 'Team',
                email: 'supportinbox@mysite.com'
            },
            {
                asignee: 'Dave',
                email: 'dave@mysite.com'
            },
            {
                asignee: 'Kate',
                email: 'kate@mysite.com'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        ticketId: '2',
        ticketDesc: 'Dummy ticket 2',
        assignments: [
            {
                asignee: 'Team',
                email: 'supportinbox@mysite.com'
            },
            {
                asignee: 'Rob',
                email: 'rob@mysite.com'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        ticketId: '3',
        ticketDesc: 'Dummy ticket 3',
        assignments: [
            {
                asignee: 'Team',
                email: 'supportinbox@mysite.com'
            },
            {
                asignee: 'Dave',
                email: 'dave@mysite.com'
            },
            {
                asignee: 'Mark',
                email: 'mark@mysite.com'
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I'd like a query that returns all tickets with a team assignment and does not have an assignment for a team member.

In the above example, only ticket 2 should be returned as it has a team assignment, and the only other assignment in the same ticket belongs to Rob, which is not part of that team (as specified in teamMemberFilter).

Comment: Do you really **need** to project this? Or are you just trying to fetch the documents that match those conditions?

Comment: Just the documents that match the conditions, I'm probably over complicating things!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you think you need to use the aggregation filter for this when a simple query will suffice:

```js
db.tickets.find({
    "$and": [
        { "assignments.asignee": "Team" },
        { "assignments.asignee": {"$nin": teamMemberFilter } }
    ]
})
```

Matches everything that has "Team" as an "asignee" but does not have anyone in the listed array.

If for some reason you **really** needed the logic to be evaluated in an aggregation pipeline, then you can apply the same with logical operators instead:

```js
db.tickets.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "matched": {
      "$let": {
        "vars": {
          "names": { "$map": {
            "input": "$assignments",
            "as": "a",
            "in": "$$a.asignee"
          }}
        },
        "in": {
          "$and": [
            { "$eq": [ 
              { "$size": { "$setIntersection": [ "$$names", ["Team"] ] } },
              1
            ]},
            { "$eq": [ 
              { "$size": { "$setIntersection": [ "$$names", teamMemberFilter ] } },
              0
            ]},
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

That will only return `true` on the second document and is greatly simplified by the [**`$map`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) and [**`$setIntersection`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/) operators for processing the array contents.

Comment: I believe this will return ticket 3 as well as it contains an assignment to Mark which is not in the teamMemberFilter.

Comment: @PixelSheep Have you tried? I did. Returns one document only.

Comment: You are a guru! I got my rest of the query to work with the $project you suggested. I am not sure why it didn't work with something like this:
$match: {
    $and: [
        {
            assignments: {
                $elemMatch: {
                    'asignee': 'Team'
                }
            }
        },
        {
            assignments: {
                $elemMatch: {
                    'asignee': {"$nin": teamMemberFilter }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

Comment: @PixelSheep because $elemMatch  does something completely different to what you seem to think it does. Hence why I don't use it in the query. But that is another question entirely.